# Is it possible to ignore classes from being instrumented based off of package folder?

Tags: byte-buddy

We currently have `ByteBuddy` injecting some code into every method of a particular package, for example, `com.contoso.widgets`.  This is working great!

However, we also have tests in the `tst` folder for the same package, for which we do not want to have `ByteBuddy` instrument on (but we do want the entities under test -- in the same package -- to be instrumented!).

Is there a way to define `AgentBuilder` so that it ignores all classes that come from `tst`, rather than `src`?  It feels like I might be missing something obvious but haven't been successful after combing through the docs.

Answer (score 0):

ByteBuddy works on byte code level, not on file system level. Have you tried to exclude tests by class name, e.g.

```java
.type(not(nameEndsWith("Test").or(nameEndsWith("IT"))))
```

Or maybe you want to try something like excluding all classes containing methods annotated by `@Test` - untested, but maybe similar to this:

```java
.type((typeDescription, classLoader, module, classBeingRedefined, protectionDomain) ->
  typeDescription
    .getDeclaredMethods()
    .filter(inDefinedShape -> inDefinedShape.getDeclaredAnnotations().isAnnotationPresent(Test.class))
    .size() == 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Byte Buddy supports a RawMatcher where any type's ProtectionDomain is supplied. A protection domain offers access to the types's CodeSource from which you can find the file system location of its class file.

Do however note that this value depends on class loader, OS, packaging format and deployment. It might work for a standardized test environment but can fail you if you derive from it. It's therefore recommended to rely on something more structured.